# JS/jQuery to create mobile nav from Wordpress nav

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, wordpress, nav

I'm trying to build a mobile nav from a nav generated by Wordpress using Javascript/jQuery and inject it into the document.

One of the menu items has another unordered list as a submenu and this is what is getting me stuck:

```
<ul>
    <li>Item 1</li>
    <li>Item 2 - Has Sub Menu
        <ul>
            <li>Sub 1<li>
            <li>Sub 2<li>                
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li>Item 1</li> 
</ul>
```

I've not been able to determine the most suitable way to select the elements. Ultimately I can't work out how to maintain the submenu structure. The jQuery approach I have tried `$('.navbar-nav li')`, this of course gets all the list items so structure is lost.

Really. I just want to be able to look at the nav and cycle over the items, add logic to build the submenu if the list item contains another unordered list.

I've considered using another script to check if there are any ULs within LIs and add classes to the elements I can refer to after when building the menu but this seems messy.

Comment: Nothing in your structure uses the class `.navbar-nav`. What exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: Sorry I can see my question was confusing. That's the css class on the nav ul, using that to get the list items within it sort of thing.

Comment: My probem is solved by the answer below, JS not at all necessary.

Answer (score 0):

Use this useful link:

**Register a Mobile Menu**

If your WordPress theme does not already provide you a mobile menu, you can register one using the below code. You can add the code to `functions.php` of your child theme or a custom plugin.

```
// register a mobile menu
function wdm_register_mobile_menu() {
    add_theme_support( 'nav-menus' );
    register_nav_menus( array('mobile-menu' => __( 'Mobile Menu', 'wdm' )) );
}
add_action( 'init', 'wdm_register_mobile_menu' );
```

https://wisdmlabs.com/blog/4-easy-steps-to-adding-a-mobile-menu-on-your-wordpress-website/

Comment: This is a much easier solution. Thank you so much!